# Maven release not working - "Maven executable not found"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-release-plugin

I recently had to get a new computer at work, and reinstall all programming stuff including Maven. Now I'm trying to release a project change, but I can't get Maven Release to work.

1. I ran mvn release:prepare from Eclipse, and it completed successfully.
2. I started mvn release:perform from Eclipse, and it failed with a message saying prepare had failed mid-way.
3. I ran release:prepare from Eclipse again, and now it failed with **"Maven executable not found at: C:\Users\bls\Git\events\EMBEDDED\bin\mvn.bat"**
4. I ran mvn release:prepare from cmd prompt, and it completed successfully.
5. I ran mvn release:perform from cmd prompt, it gave me some questions and failed with "Unable to tag SCM"

-

- **There never used to be any folder at C:\Users\bls\Git\events\EMBEDDED\bin**
- C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin includes both mvn.bat and mvn.cmd.
- C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin is added in PATH.
- In Eclipse, Window/Prefrences/Maven/Installations I added the proper path and set it to default.

Still not working. Ideas?

Comment: I agree with @khmarbaise -- doing releases through an IDE is... a REALLY bad idea. After you've done a few releases and they've failed and then wasted hours figuring out why it doesn't work from your IDE, you'll know why. The console is your friend.

Comment: Me and my team have been doing releases through Eclipse for years without trouble, so I don't know why it would be discouraged.

Comment: Making releases is a job for CI solution like Jenkins etc. But not from dev machine nor from within Eclipse or any other IDE...Apart from that if you have messages like `Unable to tag SCM` you should check if you already have the tag in your version control etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need to rename the mvn.cmd file into mvn.bat folder. In mvn 3.3.x the structure of maven have changed. The mvn.bat file have been changed into mvn.cmd. But in command line this is not taken into consideration. Hope i have help you with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Progamactor is correct.  You need to

1. Create the mvn.bat at the location maven complains it needs one.
2. Add the following contents to that batch (mvn.bat):

   ```
   @mvn.cmd %*
   ```

Comment: copying mvn.cmd to mvn.bat worked, but trying to forward from the `.bat` file to `.cmd` did not work.